# Excel VBA, code in worksheet not working

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I have the following code in sheet1 (note - this code is in the wroksheet object, not the workbook object or a module):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim r As Integer
r = ActiveCell.Row
Cells(r - 1, 7).Value = Now()
ActiveWorkbook.save
End Sub
```

Can someone tell me why:
1. the ActiveWorkbook.save doesnt work above - it gets stuck in an infinite loop instead;
2. why I cant step throught the code by just pressing F8

I tried to put the ActiveWorkbook.save in a separate module and then call that function from the code in the worksheet but that got stuck in an infinite loop as well.

Comment: By updating the worksheet you again trigger the change event, and so on to create an infinite loop.  You need to disable events using `Application.EnableEvents = False` just before you do the update, then switch events back on after.

Comment: Infinite looping ;-)  +1 @TimWilliams

Comment: Thnks for the quick reply, if I put Application.EnableEvents = False right before Cells(r - 1, 7).Value = Now(), then Cells(r - 1, 7).Value = Now() does not work. I dont get infinite loop if I take out the ActiveWorkbook.save, so is this line trigering a change event (does saving a file constitute a change event)

Comment: Do you have any other event handling in your code?  You may have inadvertently switched off event handling while working on your code (the setting is persistent), so try running `Application.EnableEvents = True` in the Immediate pane of the VBE.  Or put a breakpoint in your code so you can be sure it's actually getting triggered.

Comment: ok, so I got the     application.enableevents = true working, but I am back to square1. now I have application.enableevents = false right above  ActiveWorkbook.save and then I have     application.enableevents = false right after it, but still getting stuck in a loop. Also what I find surprising is that if I just take the line     ActiveWorkbook.save out of my code above, it works fine, doesnt get stuck a in a loop, though logically thinking I should expect it to because as soon as     Cells(r - 1, 7).Value = Now() is executed it should call the change event. but it works fine.

Comment: btw I am using 2003, just thought I'd mention

Comment: the event switch should wrap around the cell update, not the Save .

Answer (score 3):

You need to disable events to avoid the infinite loop

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
application.enableevents=false
    Cells(target.row - 1, 7).Value = Now()
application.enableevents=true

ActiveWorkbook.save
End Sub
```

Comment: I have copied and pasted your code exactly as given, I dont get the infinite loop, but then Cells(target.row - 1, 7).Value = Now()
 is not working

Answer (score 1):

The infinite loop is caused because when you update the cell with the current date this is causing a worksheet change event which is calling the event code again. You need to disable events as shown below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim r As Integer
r = ActiveCell.Row

Application.EnableEvents = False    
Cells(r - 1, 7).Value = Now()    
Application.EnableEvents = True    
ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, I opened a new workbook and copied your code exactly to the sheet 1 object and ran it. It doesnt get stuck in a loop any more, but also, it doesnt do anything. In fact if I put a break in the code, this sub is not even being called anymore. Any ideas? I do appreciate your help.

Comment: @user1894469 if you broke this code part way through, you may have disabled `Events` and not re-enabled them. in the `Immediate` window of the VBE, type `Application.EnableEvents = True` and then try your code again